Excel VBA Compile Error: Method or data member not found
I am trying to run a script to automatically copy over results from several .csv files into different tabs in an excel file. Almost the identical code works in a different code but it's giving me a compile error on the lineLine = source.ReadLine The code I have is as follows:
' Set up array for all result directories
LC1a_Gap(1) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Sample_to_Drum.csv"
LC1a_Gap(2) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Bot_Drum_to_Module.csv"
LC1a_Gap(3) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Module_to_Sleeve.csv"
LC1a_Gap(4) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Sleeve_to_TRIO.csv"
LC1a_Gap(5) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Bellow_to_Drum.csv"
LC1a_Gap(6) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Bellow_to_Module.csv"
LC1a_Gap(7) = "D:\Atlas\LoadCase1a\Top_Drum_to_Module.csv"

Comp_Gaps(1) = "Import Sample_to_Drum"
Comp_Gaps(2) = "Import Drum_to_Module"
Comp_Gaps(3) = "Import Module_to_Sleeve"
Comp_Gaps(4) = "Import Sleeve_to_TRIO"
Comp_Gaps(5) = "Import Bellow_to_Drum"
Comp_Gaps(6) = "Import Bellow_to_Module"
Comp_Gaps(7) = "Import TopDrum_to_Module"

Delimiter = ","
Ind = 2

For ii = 1 To Gaps
    Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Comp_Gaps(ii))
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set source = FSO.OpenTextFile(LC1a_Gap(ii))
    
    Range("I" & Ind).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = LC1a_Gap(ii)
    Line = source.ReadLine
    Do While source.AtEndofStream = False
        Line = source.ReadLine
        LineElements = Split(Line, Delimiter)
        For pp = LBound(LineElements) To UBound(LineElements)
            target.Cells(Ind, pp + 1).Value = LineElements(pp)
        Next pp
        Ind = Ind + 1
    Loop
    Set source = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Ind = 2
Next

I did check to make sure the files exist, but I'm unclear why this line is throwing an error in this macro but works fine in other macros.

Helps to include your variable declarations.

...we need to know what type of thing source is intended to be.   Also check there are no other objects in that VB project named source (module names, sheet codenames, etc)

@Tim clearly it's intended to be a variant/textstream (or object/textstream if Dim'd)  That said your suggestion of a naming conflict is likely the root cause.

@chrisneilsen - I agree but clarity is sometimes best made explicit

@TimWilliams the source is a separate csv file that I am copying in to an excel worksheet for postprocessing.

Did you declare all of your variables?

see https://spreadsheeto.com/vba-dim/ for example

@TimWilliams Yes all of the variables are declared. It is having an issue with the 'Line = source.ReadLine' command.

Please see my first and second comments.  You've not included your variable declarations in your posted code, which makes it more difficult for us to help you. The compiler error is telling you that whatever type of thing source is, that type doesn't have a ReadLine method.  As noted, that's either because you've declared source as the wrong type of varaible, or something else in your VB project (such as a code module for example) has the name source and that's confusing the compiler.  We can't see your project, so there's no way for us to know unless you tell us.
